# C# BestPractice: Is it ok to have more than one Settings file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I know it's possible to use more than one .settings file, but is it a best practice to do so? The only way I can seem to do it is by copy/pasting a file since Add>Item... doesn't have a settings file listed in it.

Comment: Are you sure about that last point? My copy of VS2010 has a Settings File template available from the Project -> Add -> New Item screen...

Comment: Well, then I simply can't find it... where is it to be exact? I typed "setting" in the search so it can find it faster, nothing. I went through every option, unless I glanced over it.

Comment: Ah, I found it... but it's not in the list if I try to add it to my "server" project (asp.net project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with having multiple settings files but I do think having two `*.settings` files is confusing. I'm not sure what reason there would do that I'm sure other .net developers would be equally confused as well. If for some reason you need another settings file don't name it `*.settings`.